# Why do I have to hit "Enter" Twice?

Tags: c, validation

I've been working on this for days now and finally have it validating like I want and everything works. But when I'm running this and I put in a first name and hit "Enter", the console just skips down a line. When I hit "Enter" a second time, the program proceeds to go to the next question. Any ideas why this is? Any advice is appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "person.h"

// Program Contstants
#define INTEREST    .03         // Annual Interest Rate
#define CHAR_LEN    40          // Maximum Character Length
#define MAX_CUST    2           // Maximum Amount of Customers
#define MIN_PRIN    1000        // Minimum Principal Balance
#define MAX_PRIN    1000000     // Maximum Principal Balance
#define MIN_TERM    5           // Minimum Loan Term (Years)
#define MAX_TERM    30          // Maximum Loan Term (Years)

// Program Variables
struct person *customer = NULL;         // Pointer to the "person" Structure
FILE *ifp;                              // File Pointer
int num_cust = 0;

// Function Prototypes
void addCustomer();                         // Function to Add a Customer
struct person *findCustomer(int custID);    // Function to Find a Customer
void printCustomer();                       // Function to Print a Customer
float calcMonthlyPayment(float, int);       // Function to Calculate monthlyPayment
float calcActualPayment(int, float);        // Function to Calculate actualPayment
void flushLine();                           // Function to Clear "scanf" Input

int main(void)
{
    char input;             // Local Variable to Hold User's Choice

    ifp = fopen("Customers.txt", "w");      // Opens/Creates the File to be Written - Overwrites Existing File

    for(;;)                 // Infinite "FOR" Loop to Run the Program
    {
        // Print Statements to Display the Menu
        printf("\n\nChoose From the Options Below:\n");
        printf("Type 'N' to Add a New Customer\n");
        printf("Type 'P' to Print a Customer's Information\n");
        printf("Type 'Q' to Quit the Program\n\n");
        scanf(" %c", &input);           // Scans User Input and Assigns to "input" Variable
        flushLine();                    // Calls the "flushLine" Function to Clear the "scanf"

        switch(toupper(input))          // Switch Statement to Control Function Calls. Converts input to Upper Case
        {
            case 'N':                                           // If the User Chose "N"
                ifp = fopen("Customers.txt", "a");              // Appends Data to the Open File
                addCustomer();                                  // Calls the "addCustomer()" Function
                break;                                          // Break Statement to Exit the Switch Statement
            case 'P':                                           // If the User Chose "P"
                printCustomer();                                // Calls the "printCustomer()" Function
                break;                                          // Break Statement to Exit the Switch Statement
            case 'Q':                                           // If the User Chose "Q"
                exit(0);                                        // Exits the Program
            default:                                            // If the User Chose Anything Else
                printf("Invalid Entry. Please Reenter.\n");     // Prints an Error Message
                break;                                          // Break Statement to Exit the Switch Statement
        }
    }
}

void addCustomer()
{
    struct person *cur, *prev, *new_node;                       // Defines Pointers for the "person" Structure

    new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct person));                   // Allocates Space For a New Customer and Assigns it to the "new_node" Variable

    if((new_node == NULL) || (num_cust == MAX_CUST))                    // If the "new_node" Variable is Empty
    {
        printf("The Database is Full. You Cannot Add a New Customer.");     // Alerts the User that there is No Room
        return;                             // Return Statement
    }

    printf("\nEnter the Customer ID: ");    // Prompts the User to Enter a Customer ID
    scanf("%d", &new_node->custID);         // Scans User Input and Assigns it to the "custID" field for the New Customer
    flushLine();                            // Calls the "flushLine" Function to Clear the "scanf"

    while((new_node->custID <= 0) || (new_node->custID > MAX_CUST))     // Validates the Customer ID is Numeric and Between 0 - 100
    {
        printf("\nInvalid Entry. The Customer ID must be Numeric and Below %d.\n", MAX_CUST);   // Prints an Error Message
        printf("Enter the Customer ID: ");                          // Prompts the User to Reenter the Customer ID
        scanf("%d", &new_node->custID);                     // Scans User Input and Assigns it to the "custID" field for the New Customer
        flushLine();                        // Calls the "flushLine" Function to Clear the "scanf"
    }

    for(cur = customer, prev = NULL; cur != NULL && new_node->custID > cur->custID; prev = cur, cur = cur->next)
    {
        continue;
    }       

    if(cur != NULL && new_node->custID == cur->custID)          // Tests Whether or Not the Customer ID is a Duplicate
    {
        printf("This Customer ID Already Exists.\n");           // Prints an Error Message
        free(new_node);                                         // Releases the Reserved Memory
        return;                                                 // Return Statement
    }

    fprintf(ifp, "%s", "Customer ID:\t\t");                     // Prints the Customer ID Heading to File
    fprintf(ifp, "%d", new_node->custID);                       // Prints the Customer ID to File

    printf("\nEnter Customer's First Name: ");                  // Prompts the User for the Customer's First Name
    fgets(new_node->fName, 41, stdin);                          // Gets Input and Assigns it to the "fName" Variable


    while(strlen(new_node->fName) == 0)
    {
        printf("\nYou Cannot Leave this Field Blank.");
        printf("\nEnter the Customer's First Name: ");
        gets(new_node->fName);
    }   

    fprintf(ifp, "%s", "\nCustomer Name:\t\t");                 // Prints the Customer Name Heading to File
    fprintf(ifp, "%s", new_node->fName);                        // Prints the Customer's First Name to File
    flushLine();                                                // Calls the "flushLine" Function to Clear the "scanf"

    printf("\nEnter Customer's Last Name: ");                   // Prompts the User for the Customer's Last Name
    scanf("%40[^\n]s", new_node->lName);                            // Scans the Input and Assigns it to the "lName" Variable
    fprintf(ifp, "%s", " ");                                    // Prints a Space to File
    fprintf(ifp, "%s", new_node->lName);                        // Prints the Customer's Last Name to File
    flushLine();                                                // Calls the "flushLine" Function to Clear the "scanf"

    printf("\nEnter Customer's Street Address: ");              // Prompts the User for the Customer's Address
    scanf("%40[^\n]s", new_node->address);                      // Scans the Input and Assigns it to the "address" Variable
    fprintf(ifp, "%s", "\nCustomer Address:\t");                // Prints the Customer Address Heading to File
    fprintf(ifp, "%s", new_node->address);                      // Prints the Customer's Address to File
    flushLine();                                                // Calls the "flushLine" Function to Clear the "scanf"

    printf("\nEnter Customer's City: ");                        // Prompts the User for the Customer's City
    scanf("%40[^\n]s", new_node->city);                         // Scans the Input and Assigns it to the "city" Variable
    fprintf(ifp, "%s", "\n\t\t\t");                             // Prints Spacing to File
    fprintf(ifp, "%s", new_node->city);                         // Prints the Customer's City to File
    flushLine();                                                // Calls the "flushLine" Function to Clear the "scanf"

    printf("\nEnter Customer's 2-Digit State: ");               // Prompts the User for the Customer's State
    scanf("%2s", new_node->state);                              // Scans the Input and Assigns it to the "state" Variable
    fprintf(ifp, "%s", ", ");                                   // Prints Spacing to File
    fprintf(ifp, "%s", new_node->state);                        // Prints the Customer's State to File
    flushLine();                                                // Calls the "flushLine" Function to Clear the "scanf"

    printf("\nEnter Customer's 5-Digit Zip Code: ");            // Prompts the User for the Customer's Zip
    scanf("%5s", new_node->zip);                                // Scans the Input and Assigns it to the "zip" Variable
    fprintf(ifp, "%s", " ");                                    // Prints Spacing to File
    fprintf(ifp, "%s", new_node->zip);                          // Prints the Customer's Zip to File
    flushLine();                                                // Calls the "flushLine" Function to Clear the "scanf"

    printf("\nEnter the Customer's Principal: ");               // Prompts the User for the Customer's Principal
    scanf("%f", &new_node->principal);                          // Scans the Input and Assigns it to the "principal" Variable
    flushLine();                                                // Calls the "flushLine" Function to Clear the "scanf"

    // While Loop to Test for In-Range Principal Input
    while((new_node->principal < MIN_PRIN) || (new_node->principal > MAX_PRIN))
    {
        printf("Invalid Entry. The Customer's Principal must be Between %d and %d.\n", MIN_PRIN, MAX_PRIN);     // Prints an Error Message
        printf("\nEnter Customer's Principal: ");               // Prompts the User to Reenter the Principal
        scanf("%f", &new_node->principal);                      // Scans the Input and Assigns it to the "principal" Variable
        flushLine();                                            // Calls the "flushLine" Function to Clear the "scanf"
    }

    fprintf(ifp, "%s", "\nPrincipal:\t\t$");                    // Prints the Principal Heading to File
    fprintf(ifp, "%.2f", new_node->principal);                  // Prints the Customer's Principal to File

    printf("\nEnter the Customer's Loan Term (In Years): ");    // Prompts the User for the Customer's Loan Term
    scanf("%d", &new_node->yearlyTerm);                         // Scans the Input and Assigns it to the "yearlyTerm" Variable
    flushLine();                                                // Calls the "flushLine" Function to Clear the "scanf"

    // While Loop to Test for In-Range Yearly Term Input
    while((new_node->yearlyTerm < MIN_TERM) || (new_node->yearlyTerm > MAX_TERM))
    {
        printf("Invalid Entry. The Loan Term must be Between %d and %d.\n", MIN_TERM, MAX_TERM);                // Prints an Error Message
        printf("\nEnter the Customer's Loan Term (In Years): ");    // Prompts the User to Reenter the Yearly Term
        scanf("%d", &new_node->yearlyTerm);                     // Scans the Input and Assigns it to the "yearlyTerm" Variable
        flushLine();                                            // Calls the "flushLine" Function to Clear the "scanf"
    }

    fprintf(ifp, "%s", "\nYearly Term:\t\t");                   // Prints the Yearly Term Heading to File
    fprintf(ifp, "%d", new_node->yearlyTerm);                   // Prints the Customer's Yearly Term to File

    float payment = calcMonthlyPayment(new_node->principal, new_node->yearlyTerm);  // Calls the "calcMonthlyPayment()" Function and Assigns it to the "payment" Variable
    new_node->monthlyPayment = payment;                         // Assigns the "payment" Variable to the Customer's "monthlyPayment" Variable
    fprintf(ifp, "%s", " Years\nMonthly Payment:\t$");          // Prints the Monthly Payment Heading to File
    fprintf(ifp, "%.2f", new_node->monthlyPayment);             // Prints the Customer's Monthly Payment to File

    float actPayment = calcActualPayment(new_node->yearlyTerm, payment);    // Calls the "calcActualPayment()" Function and Assigns it to the "actPayment" Variable
    new_node->actualPayment = actPayment;                       // Assigns the "actPayment" Variable to the Customer's "actualPayment" Variable
    fprintf(ifp, "%s", "\nActual Payment:\t\t$");               // Prints the Actual Payment Heading to File
    fprintf(ifp, "%.2f", new_node->actualPayment);              // Prints the Customer's Actual Payment to File
    fprintf(ifp, "%s", "\n--------------------------------------------\n");     // Prints a Line Seperater to File

    fclose(ifp);                                                // Closes the .txt File

    new_node->next = cur;                                       

    if (prev == NULL)                                           
    {
        customer = new_node;                                    
    }

    else
    {
        prev->next = new_node;                                   
    }

    num_cust++;
}

struct person *findCustomer(int custID)
{
    struct person *p;

    for(p = customer; p != NULL && custID > p->custID; p = p->next)
    {
        continue;       // DO I NEED THIS? Works through structure
    }

    if (p != NULL && custID == p->custID)
    {
        return p;
    }

    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}

void printCustomer()
{
    int custID;
    struct person *p;

    printf("\nEnter Customer ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &custID);
    flushLine();                    // Calls the "flushLine" Function to Clear the "scanf"

    p = findCustomer(custID);

    if(p != NULL)
    {
        printf("\nCustomer ID:\t\t%d", p->custID);
        printf("\nCustomer Name:\t\t%s %s", p->fName, p->lName);
        printf("\nCustomer Address:\t%s", p->address);
        printf("\n\t\t\t%s, %s %s", p->city, p->state, p->zip);
        printf("\nCustomer Principal:\t$%.2f", p->principal);
        printf("\nCustomer Loan Term:\t%d Years", p->yearlyTerm);
        printf("\nMonthly Payment:\t$%.2f", p->monthlyPayment);     
        printf("\nActual Payment:\t\t$%.2f", p->actualPayment);
    }

    else
    {
        printf("The Customer ID Wasn't Found.\n");
    }
}

float calcMonthlyPayment(float principal, int yearlyTerm)
{
    int monthlyTerm = yearlyTerm * 12;
    float monthlyIR = INTEREST / 12;
    float payment = principal * monthlyIR * (pow(1 + monthlyIR, monthlyTerm) / (pow(1 + monthlyIR, monthlyTerm)-1));

    return payment;
}

float calcActualPayment(int yearlyTerm, float monthlyPayment)
{
    int monthlyTerm = yearlyTerm * 12;
    float actPayment = monthlyPayment * monthlyTerm;

    return actPayment;
}

void flushLine() 
{
    int c;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Person.h

```
// Program Constants
#define CHAR_LEN    40

struct person 
{
    int custID;
    char fName[CHAR_LEN + 1];
    char lName[CHAR_LEN + 1];
    char address[CHAR_LEN + 1];
    char city[CHAR_LEN + 1];
    char state[3];
    char zip[6];
    float principal;
    int yearlyTerm; 
    float monthlyPayment;
    float actualPayment;    
    struct person *next;
};
```

Comment: why aren't you using `gets` once and `scanf` the second time?

Comment: Not testing the return value from `scanf` is always asking for surprises.

Comment: ^ ... and they're both used wrongly

Comment: I think you meant to ask why I AM and that's because I've been messing with the code for a while trying to figure it out and didn't change that one back to gets() before I submitted my question. LOL Thanks!

Comment: You probable have a bug elsewhere, but a bug here is the reason you can't figure out where it is -- you don't flush the prompt, so it doesn't get sent. Either put a `\n` at the end or call `fflush`.

Comment: Don't call `fflush(stdin)` @DavidSchwartz

Comment: @Jens and M.M - would you mind elaborating? Still a student and just trying to figure this out. I've been working on this for almost a week now and would love any advice or info.

Comment: All uses of `gets` are wrong. In the `scanf` you have a bogus `s` on the end  (at that point the next character must be newline, so the letter `s` won't match) , but more importantly you don't check the return value; `%[` fails if no characters are matched .  You should be using the same code in both instances, I would recommend entering the loop before doing the first input. `fgets` is probably the least painful to use of the standard C string input functions

Comment: `printf` is line buffered by default. That means it won't actually output to the terminal until it encounters a newline (or some max line length). So if you want output at a certain time either end your `printf` with a newline or explicitly `fflush` stdout.

Comment: Never use `gets`.  There is no way to prevent buffer overflow.  Use `fgets` instead.  The man page is very clear about this.

Comment: @stackptr I'm suggesting he flush the output before he attempts an input operation. Otherwise, he'll see the prompt after he's already provided input in response to it, causing him to misdiagnose his problem.

Comment: @user3121023 - No, I don't get the prompt and the program actually works - just trying to find why I'm having to hit Enter twice when I input the first name. It doesn't happen at any other time. My entire code is now up, and a work in progress (I'm sure you can tell)

Comment: Nice to see the [almost] full code. But `person.h` is missing so it can't be compiled by others

Comment: @musikluver2003 If you don't test the return value from scanf, you can't besure a value was converted. If no value was converted, you start processing indeterminate values, which causes **undefined behavior**. You should always write `if (scanf (...) == 1) { got something } else { handle error }` assuming you expect/scan/convert exactly one value.

Answer (score 0):

You came pretty close with your code for last name. I copied it for first name with some changes.

Here's the changes within `addCustomer`:

```
    // NOTE/BUG: original code
#if 0
    printf("\nEnter Customer's First Name: ");                  // Prompts the User for the Customer's First Name
    fgets(new_node->fName, 41, stdin);                          // Gets Input and Assigns it to the "fName" Variable

    while(strlen(new_node->fName) == 0)
    {
        printf("\nYou Cannot Leave this Field Blank.");
        printf("\nEnter the Customer's First Name: ");
        fgets(new_node->fName,sizeof(new_node->fName),stdin);
    }

    // NOTE/FIX: modified code
#else
    while (1) {
        printf("\nEnter Customer's first Name: ");                   // Prompts the User for the Customer's First Name
        scanf("%40[^\n]s", new_node->fName);                         // Scans the Input and Assigns it to the "fName" Variable
        if (strlen(new_node->fName) != 0)
            break;
        printf("\nYou Cannot Leave this Field Blank.");
        flushLine();                                                // Calls the "flushLine" Function to Clear the "scanf"
    }
#endif
```